# How to fetch mysql database and store into variable in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a simple login system using node.js. The code that I am using to create the login system is given below.

```
 app.get('/select', function(req,res){
   pool.getConnection(function(error,conn){
       var queryString = "SELECT * FROM `installation`";

       conn.query(queryString,function(error,results){
           if(error)
               {
                   throw error;
               }
           else
               {
                 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                 var rows = results.length;
                 if(rows>0)
                 {
                   var user = results[0].sno;
                   res.sendStatus(user);
                 }
                 else{
                   res.send("Username or Password is Wrong");
                 }
               }

       });
       conn.release();
   });
});
```

On the above code, I need to fetch the details from the Mysql query and store to variables. I tried to store the `sno` from database to the variable **user** by using the code var `user = results[0].sno;` But it showing some error in the cmd console.

```
var user = results[0].sno;
res.sendStatus(user);
```

The problem is happening only with **sno**. Its not happening with any other in MySQL. I have the following data inside MySQL database.

```
INSERT INTO `installation` (`sno`, `id`, `email`, `cookie`) VALUES (NULL, '8', 'gmail@gmail.com', 'sadsadsa');
```

The **sno** is primary and increment value.

Comment: What error is there in cmd console?

Comment: CMD Console shows the following error: `E:\mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:79
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors`

Answer (score 0):

check your mysql database connection.
and check mysql module install or not in your project.